# Web2py on uwsgi and nginx upstream timed out (110: Connection timed out) while reading upstream

Tags: nginx, uwsgi, web2py, web2py-modules

I have deployed my application on NGINX. And my error.log is full of :

```
upstream timed out (110: Connection timed out) while reading upstream, client: 10.107.46.176, server: myApp, request: "GET /myApp/Home/index.load HTTP/1.1", upstream: "uwsgi://unix:///tmp/web2py.socket:", host: "myApp.eng.home.com", referrer: "http://myApp.eng.home.com/"
```

I have a Postgres DB deployed. And this is how the index.htmlpage looks:

```
<div class="clicks">{{=LOAD(c='Home',f='index',extension='load',ajax=True,timeout=30000,times=3)}}
                                {{pass}}
                            </div>
```

THis is the index.load page:

```
{{=numHits}}
```

This is my Home.py controller:

```
def index():
    numHits = db(db.opStatus.id > 0).count()
    return dict(numHits=numHits)
```

THis is working fine with the rocket server, only in NGINX its failing.KIndly help me on this.

web2py.ini

```
$ cat /etc/uwsgi/web2py.ini

[uwsgi]

socket = /tmp/web2py.socket
pythonpath = /home/www-data/web2py/
mount = /=wsgihandler:application
processes = 4
master = true
harakiri = 60
reload-mercy = 8
cpu-affinity = 1
stats = /tmp/stats.socket
max-requests = 2000
limit-as = 512
reload-on-as = 256
reload-on-rss = 192
uid = www-data
gid = www-data
touch-reload = /home/www-data/web2py/routes.py
cron = 0 0 -1 -1 -1 python /home/www-data/web2py/web2py.py -Q -S myApp -M -R scripts/sessions2trash.py -A -o
no-orphans = true
```

uwsgi-emperor.conf

```
/etc/init$ cat uwsgi-emperor.conf
# Emperor uWSGI script

description "uWSGI Emperor"
start on runlevel [2345]
stop on runlevel [06]
##
#remove the comments in the next section to enable static file compression for the welcome app
#in that case, turn on gzip_static on; on /etc/nginx/nginx.conf
##
#pre-start script
#    python /home/www-data/web2py/web2py.py -S welcome -R scripts/zip_static_files.py
#    chown -R www-data:www-data /home/www-data/web2py/*
#end script
respawn
exec uwsgi --master --die-on-term --emperor /etc/uwsgi --logto /var/log/uwsgi/uwsgi.log
```

emperor.uwsgi.service

```
cat /etc/systemd/system/emperor.uwsgi.service
[Unit]
Description = uWSGI Emperor
After = syslog.target

[Service]
ExecStart = /usr/local/bin/uwsgi --ini /etc/uwsgi/web2py.ini
RuntimeDirectory = uwsgi
Restart = always
KillSignal = SIGQUIT
Type = notify
StandardError = syslog
NotifyAccess = all

[Install]
WantedBy = multi-user.target
```

I am starting the service by : 
    sudo service emperor.uwsgi start

Answer (score 0):

Since my reputation doesn't allow to comment your question, I have to abuse the answering section a little bit hoping not to get any trouble:

Since me deploying my web2py application using NGINX all problems based on a bad configuration of uWSGI. Thus my first advice is to check your [uWSGI installation and configuration](http://web2py.com/books/default/chapter/29/13/deployment-recipes#Nginx). Especially check emperor.uwsgi.service, uwsgi/web2py.ini and uwsgi-emperor.conf.

Furthermore, it could be, that you have another web2py installation directory as assumed by default to be "/home/www-data/web2py. In this case you have to adapt nginx/sites-available/web2py.

Finally, check the user who has installed web2py. This user has to be right configured in nginx/nginx.conf

Hope these hints helps you to fix your problem. If not, please post your configuration files as mentioned above.

**ADDITIONAL INFORMATION:**

Thanks for providing your configuration files. I've compared these to my configuration and it looks fine.

But I'm little confused that you start the emperor manually. In my configuration this is done by the nginx server as configured in /etc/nginx/sites-available/web2py as follows:

```
# file /etc/nginx/sites-available/web2py
server {
    listen          80;
    server_name     $hostname;
    ###to enable correct use of response.static_version
    location ~* ^/(\w+)/static(?:/_[\d]+\.[\d]+\.[\d]+)?/(.*)$ {
        alias /home/www-data/web2py/applications/$1/static/$2;
        expires max;
        ### if you want to use pre-gzipped static files (recommended)
        ### check scripts/zip_static_files.py and remove the comments
        # include /etc/nginx/conf.d/web2py/gzip_static.conf;
    }
    ###
    ###if you use something like myapp = dict(languages=['en', 'it', 'jp'], default_language='en') in your routes.py
    #location ~* ^/(\w+)/(en|it|jp)/static/(.*)$ {
    #    alias /home/www-data/web2py/applications/$1/;
    #    try_files static/$2/$3 static/$3 =404;
    #}
    ###

    location / {
        #uwsgi_pass      127.0.0.1:9001;
        uwsgi_pass      unix:///tmp/web2py.socket;
        include         uwsgi_params;
        uwsgi_param     UWSGI_SCHEME $scheme;
        uwsgi_param     SERVER_SOFTWARE    nginx/$nginx_version;
        ###remove the comments to turn on if you want gzip compression of your pages
        # include /etc/nginx/conf.d/web2py/gzip.conf;
        ### end gzip section
        ### remove the comments if you use uploads (max 10 MB)
        #client_max_body_size 10m;
        ###
    }
}
server {
    listen 443 default_server ssl;
    server_name     $hostname;
    ssl_certificate         /etc/nginx/ssl/web2py.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key     /etc/nginx/ssl/web2py.key;
    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;
    ssl_session_cache shared:SSL:10m;
    ssl_session_timeout 10m;
    ssl_ciphers ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA:DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA:DHE-DSS-AES256-SHA:DHE-RSA-AES128-SHA:DHE-DSS-AES128-SHA;
    ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
    keepalive_timeout    70;
    location / {
        #uwsgi_pass      127.0.0.1:9001;
        uwsgi_pass      unix:///tmp/web2py.socket;
        include         uwsgi_params;
        uwsgi_param     UWSGI_SCHEME $scheme;
        uwsgi_param     SERVER_SOFTWARE    nginx/$nginx_version;
        ###remove the comments to turn on if you want gzip compression of your pages
        # include /etc/nginx/conf.d/web2py/gzip.conf;
        ### end gzip section
        ### remove the comments if you want to enable uploads (max 10 MB)
        #client_max_body_size 10m;
        ###
    }
    ###to enable correct use of response.static_version
    location ~* ^/(\w+)/static(?:/_[\d]+\.[\d]+\.[\d]+)?/(.*)$ {
        alias /home/www-data/web2py/applications/$1/static/$2;
        expires max;
        ### if you want to use pre-gzipped static files (recommended)
        ### check scripts/zip_static_files.py and remove the comments
        # include /etc/nginx/conf.d/web2py/gzip_static.conf;
    }
    ###
}
```

Please have special attention to **both** lines

```
uwsgi_pass      unix:///tmp/web2py.socket;
```

I marked **.socket** as special, but can't remember why. Maybe I missed it in the installation script, not sure.

Does this solves your problem?

Best regards
Clemens

Comment: Hi Clemens

Thanks for your time.

I followed your instruction thoroghly. 

I had installed Nginx for web2py by using the script, "scripts/setup-web2py-nginx-uwsgi-ubuntu.sh" as specified in the deployment recipes. So, i didnot go over the separate instruction stated in the book as it said all the steps would be taken care by the script.

The only difference that i found in the book and that to what is in my system is:
While the book specifies the creation of a /etc/uwsgi/web2py.xml file , the script has created /etc/uwsgi/web2py.ini file.But the contents looked similar.

Comment: I have specified my conf file in the question. Kindly let me know if  i am doing anything wrong.

Comment: I wrote some additional information concerning /etc/nginx/sites-available/web2py and starting the emperor. Have a look! Best regards Clemens

Comment: I compared my /etc/nginx/sites-available/web2py  file. Its ditto same. Not sure why I am hitting this error.

Comment: Hi, today I had a similar problem installing a new server. I could fix it by installing the python lib uwsgi with root rights and the sudo option -H.
Do you still have the problem? Are you interesting in more information?